# Problem updating Laravel Media Library from v6 to v9

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-medialibrary

I'm updating a project from v6 to v9, and after checking https://github.com/spatie/laravel-medialibrary/blob/master/UPGRADING.md i got this message at postAutoloadDump:

> In User.php line 287:
> Could not check compatibility between Corals\User\Models\User::getMedia(str
> ing $collectionName = 'default', $filters = Array): Spatie\MediaLibrary\Med
> iaCollections\Models\Collections\MediaCollection and Spatie\MediaLibrary\Ha
> sMedia::getMedia(string $collectionName = 'default', $filters = Array): Ill
> uminate\Support\Collection, because class Spatie\MediaLibrary\MediaCollecti
> ons\Models\Collections\MediaCollection is not available